Question on constructing a recurrence relation
Find a recurrence relation for the number of strings of length n defined over $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ such that the substrings $00$, $01$, $20$, $21$ never occur.
Here is my attempt: I counted by hand, and I noticed that a(1)=4, a(2)= 12 and a(3)=36.
I classify the valid strings based on the last bit, so
Let $d(n)$ be the number of valid strings ending with a 2.
Let $e(n)$ be the number of valid strings ending with a 3.
Let $f(n)$ be the number of valid strings ending with a 0.
Let $g(n)$ be the number of valid strings ending with a 1
Thus, $a(n)=d(n)+e(n)+f(n)+g(n)$.
Now, $d(n)=a(n-1)$ since the bits preceding the last bit 2 can be a 0,1,2,or 3.
$e(n)=a(n-1)$ since the bits preceding the last bit 3 can be a 0,1,2,or 3.
$g(n)= g(n-1)+e(n-1)$ since the bits preceding the last bit 1 can be a 1 or 3.
$f(n)= g(n-1)+e(n-1)$ since the bits preceding the last bit 0 can be a 1 or 3.
Putting all these together, I get $a(n)=2a(n-1)+ 2a(n-2) + 2g(n-1)$ and I cannot get rid of the $2g(n-1)$ quantity.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. ${}{}$

If you keep applying those recursion relations again you get:
$$a(n) = 2a(n-1)+2a(n-2) + 2a(n-3) + 2g(n-2) $$
We could continue applying this until we get to the first instance where this relation is true:
$$ a(n) =2g(2) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a(k)$$
If we then define $S_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n}a(k)$ and note that $g(2)=2$ we get:
$$ S_n = a(n) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a(k)$$
$$ S_n = a(n) + \frac{a(n)}{2} -2 $$
$$ S_n = \frac{3}{2} a(n) -2 $$
We can also use the fact that $S_n = a(n) + S_{n-1}$ to get:
$$ \frac{3}{2} a(n) -2= a(n) + \frac{3}{2} a(n-1) -2 $$
$$ a(n) = 3a(n-1) $$
I’ll leave the closed form expression for you.

Thank you @Nic.
